# Removing letters from words in javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to output words that have deleted duplicates.
For example:

```
"thisss iss aa senttence" => 
expected output = "this is a sentence"
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a place to ask for code, without trying to do it. We help you with problems that happen in your code. **What have you tried?**

Comment: i have tried to use st.replace

Comment: Then please edit your question and add your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Regular Expressions.

```js
var str = "thisss iss aa senttence";
var letters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".split('');
letters.forEach(e => {
    str = str.replace(new RegExp(e + '+', 'g'), e);
});
console.log(str);
```